# java Jtextfiled as google search bar?

Tags: java

Anyone knows how build a Google toolbar to search on web with java?
I have this code but something is wrong.

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                            
  try {
        String searchText = URLEncoder.encode(jTextField1.getText(),"UTF-8");
        URLDisplayer.getDefault().showURL
        (
            new URL
            (
              "http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q="+searchText+"&btnG=Google+Search"
            )
        );
  } catch (Exception eee) {
            return;
  }
```

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Please, be more specific.

Comment: I can not  import  URLDisplayer...netbeans does not get it in a normal class...

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

- called www.google.com and used the key words "java URLDisplayer". One of the result was: http://www.labath.org/docs/java/jdk1.2.2/netbeans/OpenAPIs/org/openide/awt/HtmlBrowser.URLDisplayer.html
- I called www.google.com and used the key words "download org.openide.awt" (The package of the above class). One of the result was: 
  http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/jnlp/org-openide-awt/ .

What you can do is following:

Download this jar file and add it to your class path from your Java project. Refresh and rebuild your project.

I tried it with my Eclipse installation, used your code and all compiler errors and warnings disappeared.